# Type Error in Windows Powershell Discord Bot Javascript

Tags: javascript, powershell, discord, bots

I am coding a discord bot and I tried to embed a message. In Visual Studio Code are no errors, but if I run it with PowerShell it says:

```
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received undefined
    at checkListener (events.js:112:11)
    at _addListener (events.js:348:3)
    at Client.addListener (events.js:406:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cleme\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Achievements Bot\main.js:46:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

My code is here:

```
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');



client.on("message") , (message) =>{
    if(!message.member.user.bot && message.guild){
        if(message.content ==".help") {
            message.channel.send(exampleEmbed)
}
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The closing parenthese for your client.on() method is in the wrong place. You are closing the parameter body after "message", but you need to close it after your anonymous function, as shown here:
https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#listening-for-messages

In your code, it would look like this:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content == ".help") {
        message.channel.send(exampleEmbed)
    }
})
```